# Error 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 getting IP V6 client

Tags: java, ipv6

I have this function to get the HostAddress from my request (HttpServletRequest) on Java. But using Jetty 7.x and my IP is ipV6 I have always this error with iPv6 address.

My function:

```
xxxx.getIP(request, false);

public static String getIP(HttpServletRequest request, boolean proxy) {
    String ip = "";
    log.debug("X-getHeaderNames ["+ request.getHeaderNames()+"]");
    if (proxy) {
        ip = XFordwardedInetAddressUtil.getAddressFromRequest(request);
    } else {
        String _ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        ip = InetAddresses.forString(_ip).getHostAddress();
    }
    return ip;
}
```

The error:

> DEBUG: org.encuestame.core.exception.EnMeMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [org.encuestame.mvc.controller.TweetPollController@4fc23996]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **'0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0'** is not an IP string literal.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **'0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0'** is not an IP string literal.
>       at org.encuestame.utils.net.InetAddresses.forString(InetAddresses.java:59)
>       at org.encuestame.core.util.EnMeUtils.getIP(EnMeUtils.java:210)
>       at org.encuestame.mvc.controller.AbstractBaseOperations.getIpClient(AbstractBaseOperations.java:262)
>       at org.encuestame.mvc.controller.TweetPollController.detailTweetPollController(TweetPollController.java:332)
>       at org.encuestame.mvc.controller.TweetPollController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6990b004.invoke()
>       at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedIntercepto

I know the iPv6 localhost format should be '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1' but my request always return this string '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0'

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the class you're using (`org.encuestame.utils.net.InetAddresses`) clearly doesn't support IPv6. Try using the java [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) class that Joachim mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using a [link local address, the `%` should be included in the address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices).

This is due to the fact that the computer needs to know which interface/zone the request came from to be able to reply out the correct interface.

If you're using correctly configured, Internet routable IPv6 addresses, the zone index will not be a part of the address.

In this case, I can't see a way to solve your problem for localhost/link local testing except to filter out anything after the `%` sign, or use [another class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) that works with link local addresses to parse the address.

EDIT: [Here's another - similar - question I didn't see earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080570/httpservletrequest-getremoteaddr-not-working-how-i-would-expect).

Comment: ::1 (which is the same as 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1) is the localhost address. It is not a link-local address (which are from fe80::/10)

Comment: @SanderSteffann You're right of course, trying to locate a reference, but a zone index is optional/allowed even on localhost addresses. Tomcat7 always seems to add it.